# Finding basis for orthogonal subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis for $S^\perp$ for the subspace $$ S = span\left\{\left[\begin{matrix}1\\1\\-2\end{matrix}\right]\right\}
$$
How do I start this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find a basis of the null space of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & -2\end{bmatrix}
$$
or, equivalently, to solve the system (with just one equation)
$$
x+y-2z=0
$$
The second and third variables are free, so you get two linearly independent solution with $y=1$, $z=0$ and with $y=0$, $z=1$. So the requested vectors are
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks. I was a bit rusty about the basis topic and this just jumpstarted everything.

Comment: If you wanted, could you work with $y=1, x=0$ and $x=1, y=0$?

Comment: @samir91 Yes, in this case any two variables can be taken as the free ones. I'm used to take the rightmost ones, just to be systematic.

Comment: If we had two vectors in the span, would we have two equations and then solve for add the two equations together and then do the free variable thing? Or would we just have one free variable from the beginning?

Comment: @samir91 You'd have two equations. Just solve the linear system

Comment: OK got it thanks. Everything is starting to slowly clear up

Answer (score 2):

The orthogonal subspace of $S$ is $S^\perp = \{x:x\cdot v=0 \text{ for all } v\in S\}$.  So the first step is to find the vectors that are orthogonal to S.  Let $x$ be one such vector.  Then $x\cdot v$ is 0.  We know one such $v$; let $$v=\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\-2\end{array}\right].$$

Then $x_1 + x_2 - 2 x_3=0$.  The set of vectors that satisfy this expression is a two dimensional subspace.  It's the set
$ \left\{\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\\ \frac{1}{2} x_1 + \frac{1}{2} x_2\end{array}\right\}$.

So the orthogonal subspace is
$$S^\perp = \text{span}\left\{
  \left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\\frac{1}{2}\end{array}\right],
  \left[\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\\frac{1}{2}\end{array}\right]
\right\},$$
and a basis is
$$\left\{
  \left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\\frac{1}{2}\end{array}\right],
  \left[\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\\frac{1}{2}\end{array}\right]
\right\}.$$

Comment: If you need the basis to be orthonormal, I think $(1/\sqrt{2})[-1\;1\;0]$ and $(1/\sqrt{3})[1\;1\;1]$ will do.